# C++ operator overloading different return types

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading, subscript

I'm trying to define an operator that should enable subscript on a struct. The struct consists of a vector of vectors. If a single element should be accessed then the operator works as intended, but if a row is desired then I would like to return the vector as the custom data type, ie perform a cast or similar before return.

I've tried using a template, but without luck.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#define MATRIX std::vector<std::vector<double>>
#define VECTOR std::vector<double>

#define print(x) std::cout << x << std::endl;

struct ndcpp{
    MATRIX array;

    auto &operator [] (int i){

        //This should illustrate what I'm trying to achieve
        /*
        ndcpp temp = {{MATRIX(1, VECTOR(shape()[1]))}};
        if(typeid(array[i]).name() == typeid(VECTOR).name()){
            for(int j = 0 ; j < shape()[1] ; j++){
                temp.array[0][j] = array[i][j];
            }
            return temp;
        }
        */

        return array[i];
    }

}typedef ndcpp;

class numcpp{
public:

    ndcpp make(int m, int n, double default_value = 0){
        if (m < 1 || n < 1){
            throw std::invalid_argument("Rows or columns must have a length");
        }
        ndcpp temp = {{MATRIX(m, VECTOR(n, default_value))}};
        return ndcpp(temp);
    }
};

int main() {
    numcpp np;

    ndcpp A = np.make(5, 5);
    ndcpp C = A[0];
}
```

Comment: Under what circumstances do you expect `typeid(array[i]).name()` to _not_ be the same as `typeid(VECTOR).name()`? `array[i]` is a `std::vector<double>`, which is the same thing as a `VECTOR`. How do you expect calling code to indicate that "a row is desired"?

Comment: In C++ you can only overload on different return type if the argument types differ. Otherwise no.

Comment: You can't overload just the return type.

Comment: Are you trying to use `ndcpp` as both 1-D and 2-D tensor at the same time? That will not work.

Comment: @NathanPierson It is possible to get hold of a double if double subscript is used

Comment: Also as general stylistic notes: The `struct ndcpp { ... } typedef ndcpp;` is unnecessary; in C++ you can just write `struct ndcpp { ... };`. I'm not sure why you're using macros for the definitions of `MATRIX` and `VECTOR` instead of a `using` statement, or why you have the class name in ALL CAPS. I have a better idea why you'd have a macro for `print`, but since you don't even use it that's just adding noise to this code sample.

Comment: @Quimby I want to be able to run the last line of code in main. But I do not want to create a ndcpp of ndcpp

Comment: @kgronk18 You can overload operators based on the argument count. Your `operator[]` takes exactly one subscript, not two. `i` is a single `int`, never two or more `int`s. Now, you can't actually write a definition of `operator[]` that takes more than one argument until C++23, but you could have separate overloads for `operator()(int row)` and `operator()(int row, int col)`.

Comment: `main` look like you want a matrix and a row of that matrix to be of same type. Why? Whats the advantage? I only see lots of confusion resulting from this

Comment: fwiw operator overloading is the most overrated feature in C++. It does help a lot in some cases, but sometimes it does more harm than good. Sometimes all problems are suddenly gone when you realize that you can write member methods with different names rather than overload operators to achieve the same

Comment: @NathanPierson Okay, maybe I'm unclear. I meant that if I use the operator twice as A[0][0], then it will return the element which is a double and that code will run. But if the operator is only used once  as A[0] then I would like to cast it as ndpp with dim 1 by m

Comment: In that case what you probably want more generally is a converting constructor that creates a 1 x m `ndcpp` from a single `VECTOR`. Then you won't have to write anything in your `operator[]` implementation that tries to detect what other calling code is doing.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number It is mainly for ease of use and because I have implemented some ML code in python and want to make the "translation" easier.

Comment: @kgronk18 You can access a single element by two coordinates, that's an overload on `std::pair<int, int>`. You can access a row on overload either `int`, or a `struct Row { int i; }`. Would that work for you?

Comment: @NathanPierson Can you elaborate. I'm not quite getting how it would work

Comment: I'm saying write a constructor `ndcpp::ndcpp(const VECTOR& row)` so that you can implicitly convert from a single row of m elements to a 1 x m `ndcpp`. That would let you write `ndcpp C = A[0];`. The conversion would happen when you try to initialize an `ndcpp` from a `VECTOR`, instead of _inside_ the `operator[]`.

Comment: python to C++ requires a considerable amount of rethinking. The equivalent of python in C++ is to make everything a `std:.any`, but thats a mess. Instead: embrace the type system

Comment: Looks like you try to change your method behavior based on what return type is expected. Forget that, it does not work in C++. Either use 2 or more different methods which returns different type or overload by argument type.

Comment: @NathanPierson Thank you! It worked. If you post it as an answer i can accept it.